# How to access text_resources through StringResourceModel during junit

Tags: java, junit, wicket

**I'm building a Wicket 1.6 application.**

In this I have a Parameter class and a FillParameter class to translate org.apache.wicket.PageParameters to my own Parameter class. The Parameter class has defaults (which are set during creation), the FillParameter has min/max values I check on. Both the default values as the min/max values are loaded from a text_resource.properties file using StringResourceModel.

example (line 15):

```
private int offset = Integer.parseInt((new StringResourceModel("bla.bla.bla.offset", null)).getString());
```

So far so good. This is working fine in my Wicket application.

Now I'm working on my junit tests and I want to test my FillParameters.class. This is a snippet from my current FillParametersTest.class:

```
private WicketTester wicketTester;

@Mock
Localizer localizer = mock(Localizer.class);

@Before
public void init() {
    wicketTester = new WicketTester(MyApplication.class);
    when(localizer.getString(eq("bla.bla.bla.offset"), (Component)anyObject(), anyString())).thenReturn("0");
    wicketTester.getApplication().getResourceSettings().setLocalizer(localizer);
}

@Test
public void fillParametersGoodTest() {
    PageParameters pageParameters = new PageParameters("pOffset=0");
    Parameters parameters = FillParameters.fillParameters(pageParameters, parameters);
    Assert.assertEquals(parameters.getOffset(), 0);
}
```

Alas, this is not working. The test seems to find the resource, but it doesn't get the value from that resource, resulting in:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:454)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
    at bla.bla.bla.Parameters.<init>(Parameters.java:15)
    at bla.bla.bla.FillParametersTest.fillParametersGoodTest(FillParametersTest.java:63)
```

(line 15 in Parameters is the example I've mentioned above)

I've been searching for a solution to my problem, but I can only find good examples on how to read from a resource in the test class, not how to make it work in a application class called by the test class.

I hope I've made my problem clear, and that someone can help me with it. I'm quite new to wicket, but eager to learn.

**Problem: how can I read text_resources during junit test with StringResourceModel?**

***Answer 27 feb 2015***

Ok, so I've refactored my whole application and now I've got the code working, and it's actually very simple

```
private WicketTester wicketTester;

@Before
public void init() {
    tester = new WicketTester(MyApplication.class);
}

@Test
public void fillParametersGoodTest() {
    MockRequestParameters pageParameters = new MockRequestParameters();
    pageParameters.addParameterValue("offset", "0");
    FillParameters fp = new FillParameters();
    Parameters parameters = fpo.fillParameters(pageParameters, parameters);
    Assert.assertEquals(parameters.getOffset(), 0);
}
```

Comment: Resolved 27 feb 2015

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the problem is in your Mockito rule (the `when`):

```
when(localizer.getString(eq("bla.bla.bla.offset"), (Component)anyObject(), anyString())).thenReturn("0");
```

It doesn't match the real call and thus later the value is `null`.
Play in this area.